# computationally expensive Mathematica solver crashes

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, symbolic-math, mathematica-8

I am trying to solve a system of equations with 90 equations in mathematica: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/484bbb56-7b5e-4278-8730-902844c8ccdd

Mathematica just refuses to run it after a while and it crashes. Does anyone have any tips or solutions for going around this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: same code: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/484bbb56-7b5e-4278-8730-902844c8ccdd

Comment: Interesting problem, however, I suspect it is mostly conceptual in nature and therefore off topic here; try math.stackexchange.com instead. You might try to establish whether there exists a solution. If there is, then try very small versions of the problem (let's say starting with just two unknowns) and see how the time to solve it scales with the number of unknowns.